# Sending byte[] data from SoapUI

Tags: java, soapui

I have  a SOAP API endpoint which receives `byte[]` data and I want to test this using SoapUI. But I am really in stuck  how should I send `byte[]` data via SoapUI? I have tried with `base64` encoded string but the output is not expected (I am sending signature/public key data for verifying purpose and hence verification is not working, that means data I am sending is not ok).
What I am doing wrong? Or how should I do it?
Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:x-="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
.....

    <x-:item>
    <x-:key>content</x-:key>
    <x-:value xsi:type="xsd:base64Binary">cid:1234567890</x-:value>
    </x-:item>

......
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: replacing `cid:1234567890` with `base64encoded`  converted string right? or with the raw byteArray data ?

Comment: using base64 could be hectic at times. If you have the original file content of the raw byte[] you can send it as an attachment using cid:notation. check this out, https://aswinprasanthblog.wordpress.com/2016/03/21/how-to-send-a-filebase64binary-in-web-service-request-using-soap-ui/

Answer (score 0):

To [send file data using SoapUI](https://aswinprasanthblog.wordpress.com/2016/03/21/how-to-send-a-filebase64binary-in-web-service-request-using-soap-ui/):

- include a random cid in the request: `<my:somefile>cid:1234567890</my:somefile>`
- click Attachments at the bottom, then +
- select a file
- say Yes to caching
- click "Part" in the newly attached file details and choose the cid

When sending the request it will now include the file payload in the cid section of the XML.

#### Troubleshooting

- SoapUI defaults to the run directory every time, so it's easier to drag and drop the files into the Attachments tab.
- If the Part drop down does not automatically detect the `cid:1234567890` content, check if you have malformed XML such as `--` within a comment block, e.g:

`<!--
Comment block but contains <!-- nested double hyphens - ->
-->`